# Highcharts Showing 700 as 7 Hundred on Tooltip while showing 7 on graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highcharts graph that only goes up to 99 if a number is above 99 it will be made smaller such as 700 will be converted to show as 7 on the graph but when I try to but on the tooltip for it to show as 7 Hundred it does not work. I have it currently working for 7245 but if I have 7000 it wont work either. How can I resolve this?

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/qvtnqs8r/2/

Here is the tooltip code that is the part that is failing me

```
 tooltip: {
shared: true,
formatter: function() {
    var points = this.points,
      each = Highcharts.each,
      txt = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + points[0].key + '</span><br/>',
      H = Highcharts,
      value,
      numericSymbolDetector;

    each(points, function(point, i) {
      value = point.y;
      numericSymbolDetector = Math.abs(point.y);
      if (((value)*1000)%10!=0) {
        value = H.numberFormat(value, 2, '.', '') + 'k';
      } 
      txt += '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + value + '</b><br/>';
    });

    return txt;
  }
  //pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>',

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. Should a 7 be shown as 7k? Should 7000 be shown as 7k? Or am I completely mistaken? Regardless, you have very different logic for how you handle the graph vs how you handle the tooltip, You should have another look at this part: `(((value)*1000)%10!=0)`, to be sure that it gives you what you expect.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what should be the result?

Comment: The aim is for when it is 7474 to show tooltip as 7.47k and on graph as 7.47. When it is 747 to show tooltip as 7.47 Hundred and to show on graph as 7.47.

The current problem is `if (((value)*1000)%10!=0) {
        value = H.numberFormat(value, 2, '.', '') + 'k';
      } `

    As currently it gets 7474 and does what I need but if the number is 7000 it wont do what is needed and the same for when the number is between 100-999

Comment: Any ideas on how I can do this ? As been at it for over 5 days now on same problem and cant resolve it or find any useful help any where